# can I kill a drive just by taking it out of the computer and putting it back?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I upgraded the memory in my HP microserver and in the process took my hardrives (2x WD red) out. (This turned out not to be necessary, that's what I get for thinking I can find the way to the memory chips myself.)

Anyway, after I replaced the memory chips, I dusted the front of drive bays off, put the disks back .. and while the memory works OK, one of the disks disappeared from the system and does not show up in BIOS either. I have tried another computer, with the same result (does not show up in BIOS).

I have two questions:

- Is there any chance the disk is *not* dead? I am pretty sure the answer is negative, but just in case...
- What could kill it?

To avoid the obvious:

- I did unplug the server before I started dissecting it
- I did not drop the drive
- I am pretty sure the drive worked before the operation

Comment: You cannot kill a good drive by removing it (power off, you said above) and replacing it. 

What could have have happened is that the drive stopped and the motor would not start back up. I have heard the term "stickion" to describe the above in a shop I worked in one time with IBM hardware. They came in every day for a week and replaced all the drives while they were working

Comment: ESD could have zapped its circuit board while it was out. Or, since you aren't 100% sure that it was still working right before you took it out, it could have just "died of natural causes" in the machine. The fact that two separate PC BIOSes don't detect it is not good. Does the disk even spin up when power is on?

Comment: @SamForbis good point - I cannot detect any vibration or sound from the disk on power up, so I guess it really is dead. And the reason I cannot be 100% is that the disks were in RAID 1 configuration - but I guess I would have got some warning from the NAS if it failed. Moreover, I could see missing partition in the system, which worked just before the operation.

Comment: Did you use the same cable on both systems though? Also, inspect the connector for any damaged or bent pins. I have seen a SATA drive not work simply because one of its power pins was lifted and folded back from inserting a connector improperly. I flattened it back and luckily it worked again.

Comment: @Romen  Different cables, also tried to swap the two drives .. so definitely not a cable problem. There is no visible damage on the drive's connectors.

Comment: I think from your comments that the drive just did not restart. Your comments appear to corroborate that the drive was working before you shut off the machine and removed the drive.

Comment: Drives can be like people sometimes - they don't smoke, don't drink, minimal fat & sugar intake, go out jogging every day… then one day they die anyway. I don't think you did anything wrong, it just seemed to be "its time".